# Ошибка: "Identifier expected but '^' found"

Tags: delphi

```
 constructor   Create(Image: ^ImageInfo);  // здесь
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте объявить тип:

```
type PImageInfo = ^ImageInfo;
```

и использовать его вместо ^ImageInfo:

```
constructor   Create(Image: PImageInfo);
```

Comment: Тут не пробовать, а делать надо. Типы-указатели в списке параметров объявлять нельзя, поэтому это единственное решение.